# sign out for Facebook and Google

Tags: swift, facebook-login, logout, google-signin

I am trying to implement a sign out button that depending on the current user type (Facebook vs Google) it will sign out based on which type of current user is logged in. I am able to login with different accounts but want the sign out function to be conditional based on what type of account is logged in...thanks in advance!

```
// sign out functions
    func handleSignOut() {
// facebook sign out
        UserDefaults.standard.setIsLoggedIn(value: false)
        FBSDKLoginManager().logOut()
        print("did log out of facebook...")

// google signout
        let firebaseAuth = FIRAuth.auth()
        do {
            try firebaseAuth?.signOut()
        } catch let signOutError as NSError {
            print ("Error signing out: %@", signOutError)
        }

        let loginController = LoginController()
        present(loginController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }


    func loginButtonDidLogOut(_ loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!) {

        do {
        try FIRAuth.auth()!.signOut()
        } catch let logoutError {
            print(logoutError)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try storing in the `UserDefaults` which account your user is signed in as (e.g. store a "account" key with a string value `"google"` or `"facebook"`).

Then, in your sign-out method, `handleSignOut() {...}`, test for that value, i.e.

```
let at = (UserDefaults.getAccountType())
if at == "google" {
    handleGoogle() 
} else if at == "facebook" {
    handleFacebook()
}
```

*Implement your own accessor for `UserDefaults.getAccountType`